# Lebesgue measure and matrix.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R^n}$, $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix, and $E\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be a Lebesgue measurable set.

I know the fact that $\mu(AE)=|\det A|\cdot \mu(E)$ where $AE=\{Ax \mid x\in E \}$.

But in the situation below, my calculation seems to be wrong.

Let $n=2, A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 3 \\ \end{pmatrix}, E=[1,2]\times [2,3]$ .

Then,

\begin{align}
AE&=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 3 \\ \end{pmatrix}x \ \Bigg| \  x\in [1,2]\times [2,3] \right\} \\
&=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} x_1+2x_2 \\ 2x_1 +3x_2 \\ \end{pmatrix} \ \Bigg| \  1\leqq x_1 \leqq 2,\ 2\leqq x_2 \leqq 3 \right\} \\
&=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} x_1+2x_2 \\ 2x_1 +3x_2 \\ \end{pmatrix} \ \Bigg| \  5\leqq x_1+2x_2\leqq 8, \ 8 \leqq 2x_1 +3x_2\leqq 13 \right\} \\
&=\big[5, 8 \big]\times \big[8, 13\big]
\end{align}.

Thus, $\mu (AE)=(8-5)\cdot (13-8)=15.$ And $|\det A| \cdot \mu(E)=1\cdot (2-1)(3-2)=1.$

So $\mu(AE)\neq |\det A| \cdot \mu(E).$

Where did I mistake ?

Comment: Your computation of $AE$ is incorrect. Try to see where each vertex of the square $[1,2] \times [2,3]$ gets mapped to.

Comment: First, $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} x_1+2x_2 \\ 2x_1 +3x_2 \end{pmatrix} :  5 \leq x_1+2x_2\leq 8, 8 \leq 2x_1 +3x_2 \leq 13 \right\}$ is a weird form to write a set, isn't? The set $\{f(x) : x \in X\}$ is a shorthand for $\{y : (\exists x \in X) \, f(x)=y\}$. What does your notation mean? Second, I can see that $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} x_1+2x_2 \\ 2x_1 +3x_2 \end{pmatrix} :  1\leq x_1 \leq 2,\ 2\leq x_2 \leq 3 \right\}$ is contained in $[5,8] \times [8,13]$ (since $1\leq x_1 \leq 2,\ 2\leq x_2 \leq 3$ *implies* $5 \leq x_1+2x_2\leq 8, 8 \leq 2x_1 +3x_2 \leq 13$) but what about the other inclusion?